# react native FlatList re-renders when elements have been added to the array state

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, flatlist

When I want to change the array state all of the elements in the FlatList gets re-rendered. I have checked other questions with the same problem but nope I wasn't able to solve it. First, the issue was in my main project but because I wasn't able to solve it I created a clear project with the example I gave below but still, the issue persists.
On the main project, KeyExtractor was returning a unique id.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, memo } from 'react';
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([...Array(5).keys()])

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log("----------")
      setData(oldArray => [...oldArray, Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5000)])
    }, 2000)
  }, [])

  const RenderItem = memo(({ item }: { item: number }) => {
    return (
      <View>
        { console.log("render", item) }
        <Text>{ item }</Text>
      </View>
    )
  })

  const renderItemHandler = ({ item }: { item: number }) => {
    return <RenderItem item={item} />
  }

  const keyExtractor = (item: number) => item.toString();
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        style={{ width: 100, backgroundColor: "#7132a8" }}
        data={data}
        renderItem={renderItemHandler}
        keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

https://snack.expo.dev/@sibyl/flatlist-issue

The screenshot from the React DevTools
[image: Re render example]

**UPDATE**

Updated code to use memo

**UPDATE**
Solved it by moving components that use memo to outside of app function

```
const RenderItem = memo((props: { item: number }) => {
  return (
    <View key={props.item}>
      { console.log("render", props.item) }
      <Text>{ props.item }</Text>
    </View>
  )
})

const renderItemHandler = ({ item }: { item: number }) => {
  return <RenderItem item={item} />
}

export default function App() {....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A render call will always try to re-render the children of a component.

You can utilize `React.memo` https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo to prevent the re-render of the child component if you are using functional components

Or `shouldComponentUpdate` for the old school class components https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: I wasn't able to solve it by using memo, still re-render happens. I updated the code

Comment: I Solved and updated the post again. Thanks you for memo suggestion